# getkey() work in debug mode but not in release mode in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I have this function

```
  List<Widget> allkeys;
  get_all() async  {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      allkeys=prefs.getKeys().map<Widget>((key) {
        return Text(key+ ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
      }).toList();
    });
}

in debug mode allkeys =["key1:value1 , key2:value2"]
in release mode allkeys =[widget,widget]
```

If I use only

```
var allkeys = prefs.getKeys();
```

I have in release mode

```
{key1,key2,value1,value2}
```

but it's not the format I search

why ?

Thank you

here is the full test code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var allkeys ;

  void _incrementCounter()async  {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      prefs.setInt("test1",1); // qrText need to be a Stringlist
      prefs.setInt("test2",1); // qrText need to be a Stringlist
      prefs.setInt("test3",0); // qrText need to be a Stringlist
      prefs.setInt("test4",1); // qrText need to be a Stringlist

      allkeys = prefs.getKeys().map<Widget>((key) {
        return Text(key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
          
            Text(
              '${allkeys..toString()}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide your logs using flutter run -v?

Comment: It's too long i'm limited by 1000 line in android studio and limited by 600 line in stack overflow

Comment: I hade issue in flutter github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66001

Answer (score 0):

I change my code like that and it's ok but I had to recode all the regex

```
  allkeys = prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) {
        return (key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
      }).toList();
    });
```